# Investigate whether the sequence $\frac{nx^n + 3\sin{2n\pi x}}{n}$ is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, sequence-of-function

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions defined by
\begin{equation*}
f_n(x) = \frac{nx^n + 3\sin{(2n\pi x)}}{n}
\end{equation*}
for all $x \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \Bbb N$.

Show that $f_n$ is converges pointwise to a function $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ on $[0,1]$.
Investigate whether $f_n$ is uniformly convergent to $f$ on $[0,1]$ or not.

**Attempt:**

1. For $x=0$: We have $f_n(0)=0 \to 0$.
2. For $x=1$: We have $f_n(1)=1 \to 1$.
3. For $x \in (0,1)$: I claimed that $f_n \to 0$. The proof is goes as follows:
   Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x \in (0,1)$ be arbitrary. Choose $k \in \Bbb n$ such that
   $k > \max\left\{\frac{2x}{\varepsilon - \varepsilon x}, \frac{6}{\varepsilon} \right\}$. Then, for any $n \in \Bbb n$ with $n \ge k$, we have
   \begin{align*}
   \left|f_n(x)-f(x) \right| &= \left|\frac{nx^n + 3\sin{(2n\pi x)}}{n}-0 \right| \\
   &\le x^n + \frac{3}{n} \\
   &= \frac{1}{\left(1+\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)\right)^n} + \frac{3}{n} \\
   &\le \frac{1}{1+n\left(\frac{1}{x} -1 \right)} + \frac{3}{n} \\
   &< \frac{1}{n\left(\frac{1}{x} -1 \right)} + \frac{3}{n} \\
   &\le \frac{1}{k\left(\frac{1}{x} -1 \right)} + \frac{3}{k} \\
   &< \frac{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x} -1 \right)}{\frac{1}{x}-1} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} \\
   &= \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon.
   \end{align*}
   Hence, $f_n \to f$ where
   \begin{equation*}
   f(x) =
   \begin{cases}
   0, \qquad \text{if} \ 0 \le x < 1 \\
   1, \qquad \text{if} \ x = 1
   \end{cases}.
   \end{equation*}
   Now, my intuition is said that $f_n$ is not uniformly convergent to $f$ on $[0,1]$. But, I didn't be able yet to find the subsequence such that the sequence did not uniformly convergent. On the other hand, I tried using the uniform norm
   \begin{align*}
   ||f_n - f||_{[0,1]} =
       \sup \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
           \frac{nx^n + 3\sin{(2n\pi x)}}{n}, & \text{for} \ 0 \le x < 1\\
           0, & \text{for} \ x=1
           \end{array}\right\} = \frac{13}{4} \ne 0.
   \end{align*}
   But, is this correct? Any ideas? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\in[0,1)$, then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n+\frac{3\sin(2\pi x)}n=0$$and you always have $f_n(1)=1$. Therefore, your sequence converges pointwise to$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[0,1]&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<1\\1&\text{ if }x=1,\end{cases}\end{array}$$which is a discontinuous function. Since each $f_n$ is continuous, the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: Aaah I see. Thanks for a good advice, Sir.

Comment: What about my proof for the pointwise convergence above? Does it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: What about the supremum part, Sir?

Comment: That part is not correct. That supremum is $1$ when $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 2):

There is simple way of showing that the convergence is not uniform.
Note that $f_n(x)=x^{n}+g_n(x)$ where $g_n(x)=\frac {3\sin (2\pi nx)} n$. Now $g_n(x) \to 0$ uniformly so  $f_n$ converges uniformly if and only if $x^{n}$ does. Can you show that $x^{n}$ does not converge uniformly?

Comment: What a great idea! I didn't expect this simple way before. Yes, sir. I can show that $x^n$ does not converge uniformly. Thanks for your advice!